# Finding the related doc names in Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame with two columns (`id`, `name`). The name column has related names. E.g term, related term, related line, line.

I want to find the similar names in the different rows. I have tried through cosine similarity but unable to achive this.

I have calculated the TF-IDF using pyspark. Looking for the way to get the relarted names in the different row using pyspark.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Update your question to meet the standard of [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You can use use LSH(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing); Just hash each row of `name` column and the similar hashes would show the similar `names`.